# Materialized View refresh interval granularity

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, materialized-views

I've run into something I don't understand with materialized view refresh-times and hoped someone could explain what I'm missing.  I'm on 12cR1.

When I define a materialized view with a refresh interval of N seconds, the view compiles and the underlying job dutifully records the interval and appears to have the correct `NEXT_SEC`, but the view doesn't keep on-schedule with the defined refresh interval.

An example is below.  In this example, I define a lightweight mview that refreshes every 20 seconds.  But in monitoring its refreshes, it routinely takes 30+ seconds to update.  If Oracle doesn't support certain intervals, I'd hope that mview compilation would fail, or at least that the job would be broken, rather than quietly missing its target.

Any help understanding the underlying mview refresh mechanics that lead to this result would be great.  Any advice on alternative definitions that better keep on-schedule would also be appreciated.

Thanks

Example:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TIME_ONLY_MVIEW
REFRESH COMPLETE NEXT (SYSTIMESTAMP + NUMTODSINTERVAL(20, 'SECOND'))
AS
  SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIME_OF_MVIEW_QUERY
  FROM DUAL;
```

Running the below check, I routinely get `TIME_DELTA_SECONDS` greater than 30.  I wondered why.

```
WITH QUERY_TIME AS
(SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIME_OF_THIS_QUERY
 FROM DUAL)
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(QUERY_TIME.TIME_OF_THIS_QUERY, 'HH24:MI:SS')                                          TIME_OF_THIS_QUERY,
  TO_CHAR(TIME_ONLY_MVIEW.TIME_OF_MVIEW_QUERY, 'HH24:MI:SS')                                    TIME_OF_MVIEW_QUERY,
  LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH.LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH_START,
  LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH.LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH_END_TIME,
  EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (QUERY_TIME.TIME_OF_THIS_QUERY - TIME_ONLY_MVIEW.TIME_OF_MVIEW_QUERY)) AS TIME_DELTA_SECONDS,
  MVIEW_JOB.BROKEN,
  MVIEW_JOB.FAILURES,
  MVIEW_JOB.NEXT_SEC,
  MVIEW_JOB.MVIEW_INTERVAL
FROM QUERY_TIME
  CROSS JOIN TIME_ONLY_MVIEW
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT
                TO_CHAR(LAST_REFRESH_END_TIME, 'HH24:MI:SS') LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH_END_TIME,
                TO_CHAR(LAST_REFRESH_DATE, 'HH24:MI:SS')     LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH_START
              FROM USER_MVIEWS
              WHERE MVIEW_NAME = 'TIME_ONLY_MVIEW') LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT
                USER_JOBS.BROKEN   BROKEN,
                USER_JOBS.FAILURES FAILURES,
                USER_JOBS.NEXT_SEC NEXT_SEC,
                USER_JOBS.INTERVAL MVIEW_INTERVAL
              FROM USER_JOBS
              WHERE USER_JOBS.WHAT LIKE 'dbms_refresh.refresh(%TIME_ONLY_MVIEW%);') MVIEW_JOB;
```

Here's an example check.  The job never breaks, and failures doesn't increment, but TIME_DELTA_SECONDS here grows to approx 30 seconds, occasionally hitting 40+.

```
SQL> WITH QUERY_TIME AS
  2  (SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIME_OF_THIS_QUERY
  3   FROM DUAL)
  4  SELECT
  5    TO_CHAR(QUERY_TIME.TIME_OF_THIS_QUERY, 'HH24:MI:SS')                                          TIME_OF_THIS_QUERY,
  6    TO_CHAR(TIME_ONLY_MVIEW.TIME_OF_MVIEW_QUERY, 'HH24:MI:SS')                                    TIME_OF_MVIEW_QUERY,
  7    LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH.LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH_START,
  8    LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH.LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH_END_TIME,
  9    EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (QUERY_TIME.TIME_OF_THIS_QUERY - TIME_ONLY_MVIEW.TIME_OF_MVIEW_QUERY)) AS TIME_DELTA_SECONDS,
 10    MVIEW_JOB.BROKEN,
 11    MVIEW_JOB.FAILURES,
 12    MVIEW_JOB.NEXT_SEC,
 13    MVIEW_JOB.MVIEW_INTERVAL
 14  FROM QUERY_TIME
 15    CROSS JOIN TIME_ONLY_MVIEW
 16    CROSS JOIN (SELECT
 17                  TO_CHAR(LAST_REFRESH_END_TIME, 'HH24:MI:SS') LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH_END_TIME,
 18                  TO_CHAR(LAST_REFRESH_DATE, 'HH24:MI:SS')     LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH_START
 19                FROM USER_MVIEWS
 20                WHERE MVIEW_NAME = 'TIME_ONLY_MVIEW') LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH
 21    CROSS JOIN (SELECT
 22                  USER_JOBS.BROKEN   BROKEN,
 23                  USER_JOBS.FAILURES FAILURES,
 24                  USER_JOBS.NEXT_SEC NEXT_SEC,
 25                  USER_JOBS.INTERVAL MVIEW_INTERVAL
 26                FROM USER_JOBS
 27*               WHERE USER_JOBS.WHAT LIKE 'dbms_refresh.refresh(%TIME_ONLY_MVIEW%);') MVIEW_JOB;
TIME_OF_THIS_QUERY  TIME_OF_MVIEW_QUERY  LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH_START  LAST_RECORDED_REFRESH_END_TIME  TIME_DELTA_SECONDS  BROKEN  FAILURES  NEXT_SEC  MVIEW_INTERVAL                                   
12:09:14            12:08:44             12:08:44                     12:08:44                        30.197422           N       0         12:09:04  (SYSTIMESTAMP + NUMTODSINTERVAL(20, 'SECOND'))
```